# Create new lines after comma in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have 2 sheets currently:

1. One that contains data
2. A simple "nice view" that fetches data

I'm attempting to create a new line after each comma (if one is present), so it's easier to see if a value has been found.

I am attempting to run [regexreplace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) (substitute) on values from the other worksheet, **NOT** data on the same sheet. But I just can't get it to work. It just throws back an error.

The formula I currently have is:

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,'tracking-feb'!A:F,4,false) & =REGEXREPLACE('tracking-feb'!D2:D55, ",", CHAR(10))
```

I'm trying to fetch the data from here:

[image]

edit: I am slightly dumb, so I do apologise in advance.

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by new line you mean a line break (e.g. 1 cell with two lines), you can use `Ctrl` + `Enter` for Windows or `Ctrl + Return` for Mac to insert a line break. Incorporating that into a formula will look like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, ",", ",
")
```

Comment: Throwing back "#ERROR! Formula Parse Error", can I not use the formula and search on another sheet? Does the data I'm looking to change need to be on the same sheet I use as the Formula?

As I'm attempting =REGEXREPLACE('tracking-feb'!D2:D55, ",", ",") -- I.E (Find the work sheet named "tracking-feb", look for column D2 to D55) then replace the comma with a new line.

Comment: There's a lot of things going on in your formula. I tested the `REGEXREPLACE` on my own sheet and it worked, so the error is likely coming from another part. The `=VLOOKUP() & =REGEXREPLACE()` format looks wrong to me. Typically formulas start with a `=` and don't contain another, so I would remove the second one. To make it easier to find the error you could remove the `&` and test `VLOOKUP` and `REGEXREPLACE` in their own cells.

Comment: I see. I see. I got it to work now! Problem is, it's attempting to automatically convert to a number, so it throws off "#VALUE!" -- is there a function to convert to text instead of number? (here's the error in image -https://i.imgur.com/6YnlL6r.png

Comment: Good to hear! It should not be trying to convert to a number. Can you post your updated formula? I can better advise from there.

Comment: I'll do one better, here's a link to the replica sheets - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o_OrGL8V1mtHSn7d1TUgnGvldkeyHBYhd3EYqjlccLY/edit?usp=sharing -- EDIT: I SEE WHAT I DID WRONG. THANK YOU! "+" was there instead of "&" my apologies . huge typo on my end.. Though it's still not going down on separate lines

Comment: Thanks. Swap the `+` for `&` as the former is addition while the latter is concatenation. Since your formula outputs text you want concatenation.

Comment: You're amazing. Though it still doesn't want to create a new line after each "," even with the Regexreplace formula :(

Comment: Posting more details to help future viewers. The formula was `=VLOOKUP(...)&REGEXREPLACE(...)` which is concatenating a lookup with a regex replace. What was needed is `=REGEXREPLACE(VLOOKUP(...), ...)` so the output of `VLOOKUP` is the input of `REGEXREPLACE` (piping).